# Cannot delete space in table

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to clean up tables in a rather large Word document. Part of this is removing extra spaces. I have no problems deleting spaces at the start of text, or double spaces in the middle of text, but the very last space in a cell will not be deleted.

Sample code:

```
ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(1, 1).Range.Characters(ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(1, 1).Range.End - 1).Delete
```

(note: this code is in a loop to iterate and remove the last space as long as there are spaces at the end of the text in a cell)

This is an example cell with text:

[image]

After looping several times I get:

[image]

Running the code some more times will not remove that last space. How can I do this?

Constraints: I cannot load the text in a string, shorten it, then reinsert the string in the cell as I then lose some formatting and icons that are inserted in the text.

Here is some more code as requested by Tim:

```
For Each myTable In ActiveDocument.Tables
    For i = 1 To myTable.Rows.Count
        For j = 1 To myTable.Columns.Count
            Set myCell = myTable.Cell(i, j)
                Do
                    MsgBox "|" & myCell.Range.Characters(myCell.Range.End - 1).Text & "|"
                     myCell.Range.Characters(myCell.Range.End - 1).Delete
                Loop Until myCell.Range.Characters(myCell.Range.End - 1).Text <> " "
        Next j
    Next i
Next myTable
```

Warning!: This causes an infinite loop as `myCell.Range.Characters(myCell.Range.End - 1).Text` always evaluates to a space -- it's trying to debug this that I found out the last space was not getting deleted.

Comment: That "end of cell" marker is two characters I think, not one?

Comment: ...looks like that only shows up as a single item in the Characters collection, so (eg) `Len(.Range.Text)` might be 12 but `.Range.Characters.Count` is 11.  Or are you using `Range.Text` to check for spaces at the end of the content?  Might be useful to add the rest of your code so we can replicate what you're seeing.

Comment: https://microsoft.public.word.vba.general.narkive.com/LX0i8ele/testing-for-the-end-of-a-cell-character#

Comment: Try 'ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(1, 1).Range.Characters.Last.Prevous.Delete'

Comment: This looks like a bug: I tried different ways - all are deleting asc(32) without problems - but not the last space between text and the cell marker. If there is no text but only spaces in the cell, then everything gets deleted. Interesting though: `Characters.Last.Prevous.Delete` doesn't throw an error, but does nothing in case it's asc(32) but deletes if any other character, `Characters.Last.Delete` throws an error as the cell marker can't be deleted.

Comment: @Ike That's pretty much what I figured -- I was hoping someone had a workaround of some sort.

Comment: @freeflow thanks for the suggestion, but the result is the same: all but the last remaining space are deleted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes you have to be devious....

```
Do While ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(1, 1).Range.Characters.Last.Previous = " "
    
        ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(1, 1).Range.Characters.Last.Previous.Text = vbNullString
    
Loop
```